# Magento 2 - Product price change to 0.00 in product detail page for Non-US Locale

Tags: magento2, locale, magento-2.0.4

I am facing a very strange issue after the installation of Magento 2.0.4. I have create a product with the price $12 and change the locale from Magento configuration in backend.

Below is the screenshot for the listing page.

[image]

Also find the below screenshot for the detail page.

[image]

You might have noticed the difference between two screenshot. Yes, Product detail page shows $0.00 price while listing page has retain with the price what i have added.

Product details page automatically updates correct price to $0,00 After one or two seconds ( Javascript Updates).

Find the below code for it

```html
$('[data-price-type="' + priceCode + '"]', this.element).html(priceTemplate({data: price}));
```

I have debug further in the code and find another javascript code that passes parameter to Magento 2 pricebox widget.

```html
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
    ], function($){
        var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>
```

Now i have checked the getJsonConfig() method,

```html
  $product = $this->getProduct();

        if (!$this->hasOptions()) {
            $config = [
                'productId' => $product->getId(),
                'priceFormat' => $this->_localeFormat->getPriceFormat()
                ];
            return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
        }

        $tierPrices = [];
        $tierPricesList = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('tier_price')->getTierPriceList();
        foreach ($tierPricesList as $tierPrice) {
            $tierPrices[] = $this->priceCurrency->convert($tierPrice['price']->getValue());
        }
        $config = [
            'productId' => $product->getId(),
            'priceFormat' => $this->_localeFormat->getPriceFormat(),
            'prices' => [
                'oldPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                        $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                    ),
                    'adjustments' => []
                ],
                'basePrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                        $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
                    ),
                    'adjustments' => []
                ],
                'finalPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                        $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                    ),
                    'adjustments' => []
                ]
            ],
            'idSuffix' => '_clone',
            'tierPrices' => $tierPrices
        ];
```

I did lot of debugging through the code and come to the conclusion that they are using ICUDATA for locale support.

I am stuck with this all thing, It seems it is PriceFormat issue.

Please make sure this issue arise only for certain Locale options like Persion (Iran).

Comment: Apply reindeix, clean cache, deploy static conent.

Comment: Thanks @SHPatel, Its not a reindex or cache issue. i did everything possible.

Comment: This is a bug and has been reported previously to magento team. Check this for more details -  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4077

Comment: Thanks @ReenaParekh , That bug reported by me. But i want solution to this issue because magento people will take time to update it in their next release or so.

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been resolved , kindly update your Magento2 to latest Stable version

if you have installed from GIT & Composer follow these steps :

- Than you must stach your changes
- GIT PULL Latest Stable Branch i.e. 2.1
- Composer Update
- Upgrade Magento ( `bin/magento setup:upgrade`)

else if you have installed using zip folder download than download latest from magento website and override all files using new zip 
than you need to clear cache and run

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the magento by following commands.

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
>
> php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update below code :

Path - `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Format.php`

```
class Format implements \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_NUMBER_SET = 'latn';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface
     */
@@ -104,12 +105,18 @@ public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }
        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        /* $format = $localeData['NumberElements']['latn']['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0];
        $decimalSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements']['latn']['symbols']['decimal']
            ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][0];
        $groupSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements']['latn']['symbols']['group']
            ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][1]; */
 //start updated code
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::DEFAULT_NUMBER_SET;
        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::DEFAULT_NUMBER_SET]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);
        $decimalSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['symbols']['decimal']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::DEFAULT_NUMBER_SET]['symbols']['decimal']
                ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][0]);
        $groupSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['symbols']['group']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::DEFAULT_NUMBER_SET]['symbols']['group']
                ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][1]);

  // end updated code

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
```

**hope its work for you.**